# JQuery event: $(window).focus() is not executed in some version of Edge (IE) browser

Tags: jquery, window, focus, microsoft-edge

I have the issue.

Normally, all browsers work properly with `window.focus();`

But, there are some versions of Edge (IE) browser where `window.focus()` is not executed when you reload the document by pressing the browser refresh button or <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide one configuration where it works and one where it doesn't. And you should specify in more detail what you would like to achieve. A workaround so the functionality is the same in every browser?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: can you tell me the reason how window.focus() can be executed when document is reloaded on edge browsers